# How to combine index.html file and index.php file into one index.html file using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 3 files: index.html and 2 index.php. Currently, data is passed between the pages via URL parameters and PHP. What I need is to combine index.html file and index.php file into one index.html file and to make data pass between the pages via JS.

For example, there is such code in index.php that should be transferred to index.html
`<body data-info="<?php echo $_GET["info"] ?>">`

Comment: This needs clarifying a bit. If you're combining the two files into one then surely there are no pages to pass things between? It's not certain what you really mean or want. Can you give a clearer example of what you're trying to do. Are you perhaps trying to make what's known as a "single page application" with different "views" within it, replacing actual physical pages? Most people use ready-made frameworks to help with that sort of thing.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need to make, a single page application. So how do I connect index.html to index.php via JS? In index.html I have some link`<a href="/bnc?info=Name" class="user__item">`. This link on click redirects to index.php, which  contains such code in 'body' tag: `<body data-info="<?php echo $_GET["info"] ?>">`. How do I change that code into JS code? And is it actually possible to do?

Comment: If you're making a single page application in one HTML file and don't want the browser to navigate away from it, then generally you'd send requests to the server-side code (such as PHP) using asynchronous AJAX requests and/or a websocket connection. You seem to be shooting in the dark here, I recommend finding some tutorials and related resources regarding single-page application concepts, and also - as I mentioned before - employing a ready-made, well-known framework to help you with your task...there are several out there and it would almost certainly make your life easier.